# $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|c|<1$ show that $|c|$ can be expressed as $|c| = 1 / (1+d)$ where $d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $d>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I need to show that we can write $|c|$ in the manner mentioned above. We know $c \in (-1, 1)$

I can easily show that $1/(1+d) \in (0,1)$ and $-1/(1+d) \in (-1,0)$ and to achieve the $0$ value we can just let $d \rightarrow \infty$. That is, $c=0$ if $d \rightarrow \infty$. So we have the complete interval $(-1,1)$.

Is this the correct way to approach this? Can I not do some algebraic manipulation so that I don't have to break up the interval?

Comment: $0$ is *not* equal to $1/(1+d)$ for a positive real number, $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: False for $c=0$. For $c \neq 0$ take $d=\frac 1 {|c|} -1$

Comment: Got it. So is it right to say that if we express $c$ like that it will never be equal to $0$? Then we can't really express $c$ in terms of $d$ in that manner?